# Redifferencing multiple checkpoint-avhdx'es agains the root vhdx instead of an intermediate avhdx

Tags: hyper-v, avhdx

I'm currently in this situation of differentiating avdhx-files where A1, A2, B and C represents the actual checkpoints I'm using.

[image]

I would like to convert A1 and A2 into differentials directly against master.vhdx like B and C are, removing the dependency to A.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are these standalone differential files or do they belong to checkpoints?

Comment: @EricSiron A1, A2, B and C belong to checkpoints. A does not, but A1 and A2 depend on it. I'm not sure how this happened.

Answer (score -1):

Make a copy of A and A1.  Call them D and D1.  (If you're using ReFS, this copy won't actually need to replicate the data.)  Then use the Merge-VHD PowerShell cmdlet (or any other method) to merge D1 into D.  (Again, if you're using ReFS, this won't actually move any data.)  D is now the VHD that you want from A1.  Replicate the process for A2.

Comment: Thank you Jake! I see that someone downvoted your answer, any idea why?